# Iconfy Library Didn't find class "android.view.IconTextView"

Tags: java, android

I am using Android-Iconfy library https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify

When ı enabled minify, app crashed on starting.

Logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.IconTextView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mobojobo.vivideodownloader-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:665)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:65)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
```

Build gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

proguard rules:

```
    -keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @com.squareup.otto.Subscribe public *;
    @com.squareup.otto.Produce public *;
}

-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
public *;
}

-keep class com.loopj.android.** { *; }

-keep interface com.loopj.android.** { *; }

-keep class com.joanzapata.** { *; }

-keep class android.view.** { *; }
```

Comment: I found the answer guys. I changed layout `android.view.IconTextView` to `android.widget.IconTextView`

Answer (score 1):

When using Iconify 2+, the correct syntax is:

```
<com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconTextView
   ...
```